# Creating real time bar chart / graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've got a .txt file that is updating with a new lines every second. I can either erase and write to the file each time it updates, or add to the end of the file.
I am trying to plot that data onto a bar chart.
Data looks like this inside file:

```
Word: 5
Word2: 7
Word3: 3
```

Here is what I have currently:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate():
    pullData = open("DataFile.txt","r").read()
    dataArray = pullData.split('\n')
    xar = []
    yar = []
    for eachLine in dataArray:
        if len(eachLine)>1:
            x,y = eachLine.split(':')
            xar.append(str(x))
            yar.append(int(y))
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.bar(xar,yar)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)

plt.show()
```

Comment: And what's the problem with the code you have?